# I have a string in which I want to extract both kinship and Name

Tags: java, regex, string, text-extraction

How can I write a regex that will extract "père" and "Tomy"  from the following texts?

```
myText = "Qui est le père de Tomy?";

myText = "Qui est le père aimé du Jeune Tomy?";

myText = "Qui est le père du petit de Tomy";
```

Comment: Any rationale you have for extracting text?

Comment: Simplest way would be `père|Tomy`, but if that is not what you wanted you would need to provide more context of what you actually want.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this regex.

```
père{1}|Tomy{1}
```

And to prevent multiple use of theses words in your sentences, you can also use

```
père+|Tomy+
```